# iOS Autolayout: Issues with 2 variable sized boxes and 1 fixed sized box

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I have now been bashing my head against this problem for a couple of hours and figured it was time to ask somebody else.

I have 2 views that must be the same size, within these two views there are 2 boxes (green and blue in the pictures below), which are of variable sizes, and a box (pink'ish) that is fixed size.

Here is a sample image:

[image: Scenario 1]

The green and pink boxes are set to be at the top, and the blue box floats underneath them. The blue box should never be further down than 15pt from the lowest of the other two boxes. This means that if the green box becomes smaller (as seen in the next image), then the blue box should stay 15pt from the pink box.

[image: Scenario 2]

Lastly, since the cells are fixed height then if the blue box becomes smaller, then it should stay at the other boxes, but leave space below itself to fill out the rest of the view (since it must be as big as the view next to it), as I tried picturing here:

[image: Scenario 3]

The key point here is that we are working on the smaller view of the two.
(The green and blue boxes are both labels with text that must be at the top of the box.)

The best solution I've come up with is to add:

- green.bottom >=15 blue.top
- pink.bottom >=15 blue.top
- blue.bottom >=15 superview.bottom

But I get an "Inequality Constraint Ambiguity" between them, because inequality is not "good enough".

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish and what the problem is

Comment: I redid my explanation in order to make it clearer. Basically I have two views, and a very floating blue box, which I cannot place using autolayout without getting inequality constraint ambiguities and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: Does the pink box have fixed size constraints? There needs to be a constant in those inequalities. You can set height and width constraints and remove them at build time. Or -- better yet -- modify them in the updateConstraints method of your view controller: instead of explicitly setting the pink box view's frame, you can set its size with the constraints. Then, autolayout does the right thing.

Comment: Anna, yes it has both height and width set. Though rdelmar basically has it nailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to add two more constraints between the blue view and the green and pink views. The should be,

green.bottom == 15 blue.top priority 900

pink.bottom == 15 blue.top priority 900

Your >= constraints have the default priority of 1000, meaning that they are required. This will ensure that neither view is ever closer than 15 points to the blue view. Adding these new equal constraints with a lower priority, means that the system will try to satisfy them, but it doesn't have to. This will result in the system satisfying which ever of those two equal constraints that it can, without violating the >= constraints.

I'm not exactly sure what constraint you need to the bottom of the view (from the blue view) since I'm unsure what size you want it to be.

Comment: Hey! I tried your solution, and it is basically correct. What I found was that I needed to only add the green.bottom ==15 blue.top priority 750 (xcode says this is high, so whatever let's go with that). This is because it's the varying height, and if the green box is shorter than the pink, then it uses the inequality constraints for both. For blue bottom I just added another inequality stating the minimum distance to the bottom. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @BjarkeH.Søndergaard, It doesn't matter in this case, but generally it's better not to make the priority equal to one of the default values (750, 510, 500, 490, 250, 50) because that will make the comparison between your constraint and some system set default equal, and thus ambiguous as to which constraint should take priority. Better to pick 751 or 749 (or my pretty arbitrary choice of 900) depending on the situation.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Thank you. Though I will still claim that you'll only get the right result by adding the constraint to green only (or at least not both, because both will mean that the green box is cut short if it extends below the pink one).

Comment: @BjarkeH.Søndergaard, Sure, adding one may be the right way, it depends on how you're setting the size of the green one. When I tested it, adding both worked fine, but you may be setting the height of the green box differently that I did.